# In Python, how can I create lists that contain a certain index of other lists?

Tags: python, list

Say I have several lists

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
C = [7,8,9]
```

How can I create new lists so that they contain matching indexes, as in:

```
D = [1,4,7]
E = [2,5,8]
F = [3,6,9]
```

The original lists will always contain the same number of elements, and I need this to work for any number of elements and any number of lists, not just three. I figure I need to loop over a range, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "so that they contain matching indices"? What result would you expect if `A = [1,2,3,4], B = [5,6,7,8], C = [9,10,11,12]` ?

Comment: if you just need to transpose your data. zip or have a look at numpy if you are doing any data science....

Comment: I would want D = [1,5,9], E = [2,6,10], F = [3,7,11], G = [4,8,12]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may be looking for [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> c = [7, 8, 9]
>>> zipped = zip(a, b, c)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

If instead of several lists, you have a list of the lists that you want to zip, then you can use `*` for unpacking the sublists, as follows:

```
>>> myListOfLists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> zipped = zip(*myListOfLists)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a way to do this if instead of having each list individually stored in a variable, I have a list of lists that I need zipped?